# Bitbucket app password refused for installation using “pip” but works for “pipenv”

Tags: python, git, pip, bitbucket, pipenv

I must provide access for a private BitBucket repository for our team’s Python packages to be installable from Google App Engine.

I have created an App password with only one permission “Repository Read” and was able to use it to clone my repository and had no troubles installing my package using `pipenv` but `pip` does receive an HTTP 403 from the BitBucket:

```
Collecting my-package-0.1.0.beta1 from https://my_user:****@bitbucket.org/my-team/my_repo.git@v0.1#egg=my-package-0.1.0.beta1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 35))
  HTTP error 403 while getting https://my_user:****@bitbucket.org/my-team/my_repo.git@v0.1#egg=my-package-0.1.0.beta1
  Could not install requirement my-package-0.1.0.beta1 from https://my_user:****@bitbucket.org/my-team/my_repo.git@v0.1#egg=my-package-0.1.0.beta1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 35)) because of error 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://bitbucket.org/my-team/my_repo.git@v0.1
```

In my `requirements.txt` 35th line is `https://${BIT_USER}:${BIT_PASS}@bitbucket.org/my-team/my_repo.git@v0.1#egg=my-package-0.1.0.beta1`

Cloning with command line: `git clone "https://${BIT_USER}:${BIT_PASS}@bitbucket.org/my-team/my_repo.git"` works like a charm and `pipenv` install without any trouble having thi line: `my-package = {git = "https://my_user:app_password@bitbucket.org/my-team/my_repo.git",ref = "v0.1"}` in my `Pipfile`.

Please note that when installing using pipenv, after I run `pip freeze` I see my package listed as `my-package==0.1.0b1` even its version in `setup.py` is `0.1.0.beta1`

Do I miss something?

Comment: Two things: Firstly, check according bugtickets for the software you are using. If that doesn't help, the second thing is to extract a [mcve].

Comment: Aside: You might want to consider using something like [Gemfury](https://gemfury.com/) to host your private packages.

Comment: Change the URL protocol to `git+https` in your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: @hoefling do you mind to convert your comment into the answer? Changing the URI scheme as you suggested did solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [`pip` supports installing from multiple VCS](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support), you need to add the prefix identifying the particular VCS when installing from repo URL. Git examples from the [Git](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git) section:

> `pip` currently supports cloning over `git`, `git+http`, `git+https`, `git+ssh`, `git+git` and `git+file`:
>
> Here are the supported forms:
>
> ```
> [-e] git://git.example.com/MyProject#egg=MyProject
> [-e] git+http://git.example.com/MyProject#egg=MyProject
> [-e] git+https://git.example.com/MyProject#egg=MyProject
> [-e] git+ssh://git.example.com/MyProject#egg=MyProject
> [-e] git+git://git.example.com/MyProject#egg=MyProject
> [-e] git+file:///home/user/projects/MyProject#egg=MyProject
> -e git+git@git.example.com:MyProject#egg=MyProject
> ```